# Version conflict django-oauth-toolkit>0.12.0 and urllib3==1.25.11

Tags: python, django, urllib3, django-oauth-toolkit

Why I have a problem with updating Django from version 1.11.29 to 2.0.13. When updating the library django-oauth-toolkit to version 1.2.0 - version support Django 2.0 I receive an error:  `__version__ = pkg_resources.require("django-oauth-toolkit")[0].version  pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (urllib3 1.25.11 (/.virtualenvs/django-oauth-tookit-conflict/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1'), {'requests'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because was changed in /oauth2_provider/**init**.py

**version** = '0.11.0'

**author** = "Massimiliano Pippi & Federico Frenguelli"

default_app_config = 'oauth2_provider.apps.DOTConfig'

VERSION = **version**  # synonym

To:

import pkg_resources

**version** = pkg_resources.require("django-oauth-toolkit")[0].version

default_app_config = "oauth2_provider.apps.DOTConfig"